# PhpStorm XDebug with a remote browser

Tags: php, linux, apache, xdebug, phpstorm

I have debugging enabled from my localhost - RHEL. So my phpstorm installed on localhost works fine when i request a url from the same box as the apache server.

However, I would like the debugging to work from another machine (different host). Is there a setting that i am missing to enable. that.

my ini file :

```
zend_extension = ${extension_dir}/xdebug.so
xdebug.profiler_append = 0
xdebug.profiler_enable_trigger = 0
xdebug.profiler_aggregate = 0
xdebug.profiler_enable = 0
xdebug.profiler_output_dir = /tmp
xdebug.profiler_output_name = cachegrind.out.%p
xdebug.remote_enable=On
xdebug.remote_handler=dbgp
xdebug.remote_host =localhost
xdebug.remote_port = 9000
xdebug.remote_mode = "req"
xdebug.allowed_clients = ""
xdebug.remote_connect_back=1
xdebug.idekey="mykey"
```

Comment: **1)** http://confluence.jetbrains.com/display/PhpStorm/Xdebug+Installation+Guide **2)** http://confluence.jetbrains.com/display/PhpStorm/Zero-configuration+Web+Application+Debugging+with+Xdebug+and+PhpStorm **3)** http://blog.jetbrains.com/phpstorm/2013/07/webinar-recording-debugging-php-with-phpstorm/ **4)** http://derickrethans.nl/debugging-with-xdebug-and-firewalls.html

Comment: For remote debugging you need to make sure that xdebug (yes, xdebug) can connect to computer where PhpStorm is running (and that IDE is listening for incoming connections -- "phone handle" icon as described in #2). You may need to configure firewall/router for that. If any problems -- collect logs: **a)** http://xdebug.org/docs/all_settings#remote_log **b)** http://devnet.jetbrains.com/docs/DOC-1202